# How do i find and download targets of drugs which are in DrugBank?

Tags: proteins, pharmacology, gene, biopython

Recently, I am focused on drugs and their interactions. But since I am new in this field, using experts experience would help me a lot. I have downloaded DrugBank xml file from DrugBank website and parsed the XML into dataFrames in python, and now i have drugs with their name and ID and etc. In a paper i read that we can make a similarity graph by comparing number of similar targets shared between drugs, but actually i don't know where and how i can download targets of drugs exists in DrugBank to compare their similarity. I appreciate answers that help me.